# Converting float to Decimal, incorrectly losing precision

Tags: .net, decimal, string-formatting, valueconverter

I have the following code sample:

```
        float val = 16777216.0F;
        var badResult = Convert.ToDecimal(val);
        //badResult has value 16777220
```

Why is this precision lost?  the value specified is 2^24, a value which float can represent.  Are there any .net libraries I can use to get this conversion to work correctly without having to roll my own iCustomFormatter?

Thanks!

Edit, this is the ugly code I used as a solution

```
var goodResult = Convert.ToDecimal(((double)val));
```

Comment: If you're working with mathematics, use floats/doubles all the way. If you're working with currency, use decimals all the way. Why would you need to convert between them?

Comment: see also http://ideone.com/w1sTm

Comment: @graham. I am working with return codes from hardware unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [`System.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx):

> By default, a Single value contains only 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally.

The value given is indeed correct to 7 significant digits. While the *exact* value of the float is in fact the one you've given, it seems reasonable for the conversion to string to only show the number of digits which are known to be correct, with the final digit being potentially rounded.

Comment: Well, the temporary solution I've found is this:

var goodResult = Convert.ToDecimal(((double)val));  

This conversion works, but seems, well, silly.  I know float is only applicable to 7 sig digits, but this code returns correct values.  Can I event rust that code?

Comment: @greggorob64: Well I wouldn't start converting between `float`/`double` and `decimal` to start with, to be honest. That's almost *always* a sign that you've gone wrong earlier. And while I can understand why that works in this particular case, you'd need to be *very* precise about what you wanted to get in various corner cases before I'd say whether it will do what you want. I don't see why you *want* the 8th significant digit if you know it's untrustworthy.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I have a sensor that's returning a float (no control over it), and we need values to 8 digits because if the number is over 1mil, its an error code, by design, and 2^24 is readout it emits on calibration.  It was bad design on their part, but I need to get it into a decimal for future storage.

Comment: @greggorob64: It sounds like you should convert it to a 32 bit integer if it's an error code then. You're not interested in the magnitude - you're interested in the bit pattern.

Comment: We've gotten offtopic.  The value comes in as float, and the ugly conversion above gets the job done, thanks for the help.

Comment: @greggorob64: I don't think it's offtopic at all, actually - what you're really interested in about the value guides you to the most appropriate way of using it. In this case it sounds like in *some* cases you're interested in using the number as just a simple magnitude, but in *other* cases it's basically a bit pattern... so I would recommend *using* it that way.

Comment: The 'ECM/PCM "A"' monitor hardware we're using to test batteries returns the value 12666368 as a float return code.  It shouldn't be doing that.  The runtime is always able to hold that value, correctly.  The only time the value 'becomes incorrect' is whenever you either a: try to display it using any type of string formatting (different problem), or b: the issue we're having here.  Since my code is the first chance we get to read the sensor, I'm attempting to copy it into a decimal to work with.   There are no settings on the hardware to have it return as a double, or read as an Int32.

Comment: @greggorob64: I would suggest *not* converting it to a `decimal` (which could give other problems) but converting it to your own type which contains *either* a status *or* an actual value (probably still as a float). You can use `BitConverter` to convert between `float` and `int` (admittedly it would be easier if `Single` contained an equivalent of `Double.ToInt64Bits`). The benefit of separating the single value into its *logical* components nice and early is that throughout the rest of the system, you shouldn't need to worry about the original representation.

Comment: @greggorob64: Of course if you're happy with what you're doing now, then who am I to comment? But if you're interested in an example of what I'd do, I can edit it into my answer. (It may be tomorrow though...)

Comment: @greggorob64: Righto - do you have any public documentation I could look at? I'd like to do the best job I can :) Not to worry if it's all secret.

Comment: I'm not going to be able to produce that documentation.  The only product code we have is internal and the test engineer isn't going to take the time to get me the correct documentation, even if they could.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion to decimal works fine; the problem is that the `float` type (`System.Single`) cannot represent this value exactly, so it's actually `1.677722E+07`. If you use `double` (`System.Double`), which has a higher precision, it will work as expected.